# AWS ECS agent cannot find /etc/resolv.conf when launching and cannot add instances to an ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) to add an instance to my **AWS ECS** cluster.

So I:

1. Created an autoscaling launch configuration for autoscaled instances (*AMI*: **ami-a28476c2** **us-west-2**)
2. The instance boots from the autoscale group with no issues, but never joins my ECS cluster `default` as the docs say it should.
3. I sshed into the instance and cat the logs and see:

   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-157 ~]$ cat /var/log/ecs/ecs-init.log.2016-05-10-03 
   2016-05-10T03:31:21Z [INFO] pre-start
   2016-05-10T03:31:22Z [INFO] start
   2016-05-10T03:31:22Z [INFO] No existing agent container to remove.
   2016-05-10T03:31:22Z [INFO] Starting Amazon EC2 Container Service Agent
   2016-05-10T03:31:23Z [ERROR] could not start Agent: API error (500): Cannot start container dbee780d6770f62afc3266ba14b77957a5e6054f94e89b2ced77f9636c4be64b: open /etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory

So it looks like the ECS agent is failing because it can't find `/etc/resolv.conf`. I have no idea why this is since I'm following the docs verbatim.

Has anyone tried this in the past? I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this. Using the help at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068299) page, I found that something (don't know what the cause was) was firewalling the instance.

In my autoscaling launch configuration, I added the following code to `user-data` section:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

which creates the missing file (`/etc/resolv.conf`) and tells the instance to use the Google DNS servers (presumably any DNS servers you want).

And all works great now.